# Wp-cli ошибка в терминале functions mysql_connect()

Tags: wordpress, openserver

На win10 + open server(для wordpress) поставил wp-cli,через терминал все устанавливалось включая создание конфига, но когда дошло до команды: **wp core install --prompt**, то произошла ошибка:

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\OSPanel\domains\WPdownload\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1564**

Вероятно это из за того что в новых версиях php и mysql что то поменялось и надо использовать Mysqli или PDO, в Опен сервере в Модулях такого не нашел, подскажите плз как решить эту проблему ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, в php не установлены нужные расширения для работы с базой. Когда wp-cli не находит mysqli, она пытается подключить расширение mysql, которого тоже нет.

В файле php.ini найдите и раскомментируйте строки

```
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
```

После чего перезапустите OpenServer.

Comment: если имелось ввиду это сделать в C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP-7.2, то там так стоит
`extension=php_mysqli.dll 
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`

Comment: есть еще другие идеи ?

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь насчёт конфигурации php, используемой wp-cli. Почитайте исходный код wp-db.php https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/ и убедитесь, что я прав. У вас не подключен mysqli. А файл, в который вы смотрите, не тот.

Comment: Вы правы, я правил в самом опен сервере, а у меня же еще в корне диска С есть папка с PHP7, там я раскомментил эти 2 строчки и стало почти все хорошо, прилетела одна ошибка и я не в курсе еще на что она влияет, я в php не разбираюсь:
`PHP Warning:  Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=4564 in C:\OSPanel\domains\WPdownload\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1924
Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=4564 in C:\OSPanel\domains\WPdownload\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1924
Success: WordPress installed successfully.
PS C:\ospanel\domains\WPdownload>`